# Dynamic light in html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I would like to ask how to make such effects http://img690.imageshack.us/img690/5263/dynamiclightingrev1.png in HTML5 canvas?

my code TileMap
http://imageshack.us/f/12/e2cg.png/

Comment: Divide your canvas into cells, lighten or darken each cell according to its distance from light sources. Done.

Comment: How to do it? could you please give some examples?

Comment: Questions asking for code must **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the *expected* results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe one of the filters on this site is what you need: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/imagefilters/

Comment: me this was needed. But I do not really know how to ImageData :/

Comment: my game http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jD3MuBx9WFE

Comment: I need to like http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3LNHVxfO-wc